# Attempted import error: 'PostsReducer' is not exported from './store/reducers/posts_reducer'

Tags: reactjs, import, reducers

I have been trying to figure out my issue and I am not getting anywhere.  I am getting the following message when trying to compile my react app:

```
./src/context_state_config.js
Attempted import error: 'PostsReducer' is not exported from './store/reducers/posts_reducer'
```

Here is my reducer file:

```
import * as ACTION_TYPES from '../actions/action_types'

const initialState = {
  post: [],
  comments: []
}

const PostsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_DB_POSTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        posts: action.payload
      }
    case ACTION_TYPES.REMOVE_DB_POSTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        posts: []
      }
      case ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_POST_COMMENTS:
        return {
          ...state,
          comments: action.payload
        }
      case ACTION_TYPES.REMOVE_POST_COMMENTS:
        return {
          ...state,
          comments: []
        }
        
      default:
        return state
      }
}

export default PostsReducer;
```

Here is my context_state_config.js imports:

```
import React, { useReducer } from 'react';
import Context from './utils/context';
import * as ACTIONS from './store/actions/actions';

import * as Reducer1 from './store/reducers/plain_reducer';
import * as AuthReducer from './store/reducers/auth_reducer';
import * as PostsReducer from './store/reducers/posts_reducer';
import * as FormReducer from './store/reducers/form_reducer';

import Routes from './routes';

import Auth from './utils/auth';
```

Is there anything easy I am missing? I am drawing a blank.

[image: Tree]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no named exports in your `posts_reducer` file.  There is only one export which is the `default` export.

Instead of this:

```
import * as PostsReducer from './store/reducers/posts_reducer';
```

You should just import the default:

```
import PostsReducer from './store/reducers/posts_reducer';
```